# Controlling combined value of two select inputs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have two simple select inputs with same values, from 0% to 50% in both of them. I would like to control their values, so that when their values are combined, they do not exceed 50%. So no matter which of the two inputs is changed, the other one will change its value accordingly. 
So let's say if first input has value 5% the second input should have value of 45% and vice versa.
I tried using .change function with an if/else if statement but i just cant get it to work. Needless to say i dont have much expirience with jquery.

HTML:

```
 <select id="myselect1">
      <option value="0">0%</option>
      <option value="5">5%</option>
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="15">15%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="25">25%</option>  
      <option value="30">30%</option>  
      <option value="35">35%</option> 
      <option value="40">40%</option>  
      <option value="45">45%</option>    
      <option value="50">50%</option>      
    </select>

    <select id="myselect2"> 
      <option value="0">0%</option>
      <option value="5">5%</option>
      <option value="10">10%</option>
      <option value="15">15%</option>
      <option value="20">20%</option>
      <option value="25">25%</option>  
      <option value="30">30%</option>  
      <option value="35">35%</option> 
      <option value="40">40%</option>  
      <option value="45">45%</option>    
      <option value="50">50%</option>     
    </select>
```

JS:

```
$('#myselect1').change(function(){
  if ($this.value == '5'){
    $('#myselect2').val('45');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '10'){
    $('#myselect2').val('40');
  }  
  else if ($this.value == '15'){
    $('#myselect2').val('35');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '20'){
    $('#myselect2').val('30');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '25'){
    $('#myselect2').val('25');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '30'){
    $('#myselect2').val('20');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '35'){
    $('#myselect2').val('15');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '40'){
    $('#myselect2').val('10');
  } 
  else if ($this.value == '45'){
    $('#myselect2').val('5');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '50'){
    $('#myselect2').val('0');
  }
});

$('#myselect2').change(function(){
  if ($this.value == '5'){
    $('#myselect1').val('45');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '10'){
    $('#myselect1').val('40');
  }  
  else if ($this.value == '15'){
    $('#myselect1').val('35');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '20'){
    $('#myselect1').val('30');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '25'){
    $('#myselect1').val('25');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '30'){
    $('#myselect1').val('20');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '35'){
    $('#myselect1').val('15');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '40'){
    $('#myselect1').val('10');
  } 
  else if ($this.value == '45'){
    $('#myselect1').val('5');
  }
  else if ($this.value == '50'){
    $('#myselect1').val('0');
  }
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj459ntg/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will work if you changed

`$this.value` to `this.value` or assign `this` to `$this` (`var $this = this`);

However, this can be done in a very simple way

```js
$('#myselect1, #myselect2').change(function() {
  var who = this.id === 'myselect1' ? '#myselect2' : '#myselect1';
  // if the ID of the changed select is #myselect1 who will be #myselect2 or vice versa.
  $(who).val(50 - this.value); // change the value of the other select
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect1">
  <option value="0">0%</option>
  <option value="5">5%</option>
  <option value="10">10%</option>
  <option value="15">15%</option>
  <option value="20">20%</option>
  <option value="25">25%</option>
  <option value="30">30%</option>
  <option value="35">35%</option>
  <option value="40">40%</option>
  <option value="45">45%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
</select>

<select id="myselect2">
  <option value="0">0%</option>
  <option value="5">5%</option>
  <option value="10">10%</option>
  <option value="15">15%</option>
  <option value="20">20%</option>
  <option value="25">25%</option>
  <option value="30">30%</option>
  <option value="35">35%</option>
  <option value="40">40%</option>
  <option value="45">45%</option>
  <option value="50">50%</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great solution, works exactly as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put a listener on both select boxes, do some maths to work out what the other value needs to be and the check to see which element we need to change.

http://jsfiddle.net/qj459ntg/3/

```
$('select').change(function(){
  var MaxValue = 50
  var CurValue = $(this).val();
  var NewValue = MaxValue - CurValue;
  if ($(this).is('#myselect1')) {
      $('#myselect2').val(NewValue);
  } else {
      $('#myselect1').val(NewValue);      
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great! Do you maybe know if there is a way to detect if input is changed via keyboard? Currently the other field does not change if the first field is changed by keyboard, regardless of that thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Not a problem. No idea about keyboard thing, what browser/version are you using? I'm on Google Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 m and it's working fine for me with the keyboard changing...

Comment: Im using Firefox, where it also works, however you need to hit enter first. Just tried it in chrome and it works without pressing enter. Thanks once again, exactly what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues going on.

You need to change all your statements to like:

```
if ($(this).val() == '5'){
    $('#myselect2').val('45');
  }
```

$this  is not a valid selector in jquery.
.value cannot be inter,mingled with a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#select_1").change(function() {
  var select_1_value = $("#select_1").val();
  var select_2_value = $("#select_2").val();
  
  var value_1 = parseInt(select_1_value);
  var value_2 = parseInt(select_2_value);
  
  var sum_values = value_1 + value_2;
  
  if (sum_values > 50) 
  {
    var select_2_needed = value_2 - ((value_1 + value_2) - 50);
    
    $("#select_2").val(select_2_needed + "%");
  }
});

$("#select_2").change(function() {
  var select_1_value = $("#select_1").val();
  var select_2_value = $("#select_2").val();
  
  var value_1 = parseInt(select_1_value);
  var value_2 = parseInt(select_2_value);
  
  var sum_values = value_1 + value_2;
  
  if (sum_values > 50) 
  {
    var select_1_needed = value_1 - ((value_1 + value_2) - 50);
    
    $("#select_1").val(select_1_needed + "%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id = "select_1">
  <option>0%</option>
  <option>5%</option>
  <option>10%</option>
  <option>15%</option>
  <option>20%</option>
  <option>25%</option>
  <option>30%</option>
  <option>35%</option>
  <option>40%</option>
  <option>45%</option>
  <option>50%</option>
</select>
<select id = "select_2">
  <option>0%</option>
  <option>5%</option>
  <option>10%</option>
  <option>15%</option>
  <option>20%</option>
  <option>25%</option>
  <option>30%</option>
  <option>35%</option>
  <option>40%</option>
  <option>45%</option>
  <option>50%</option>
</select>
```

You will need something like this (see snippet linked with).

Answer (score 0):

$('#myselect1').change(function(){  if($(this).val() < 50 ){ var value
= 50 - $(this).val();  $('#myselect2').val(value); }else if($(this).val() == 50){ $('#myselect2').val(0); } });

$('#myselect2').change(function(){  if($(this).val() < 50 ){ var value
= 50 - $(this).val();  $('#myselect1').val(value); }else if($(this).val() == 50){ $('#myselect1').val(0); } });

Hope this will help you.